# Can I filter a jqGrid by values in a hidden column using input in a visible column?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

My jqGrid uses loadonce: true and has a pair of columns I'm trying to filter by.  'DeletedFlag' is a hidden column with a bit flag.  The column 'Deleted?' is visible and displays either nothing (DeletedFlag == 0) or a timestamp (DeletedFlag == 1).

Is there a way to map the filter input from 'Deleted?' to 'DeletedFlag' as I have attempted in the code sample below?  If not, is there a way to change the 'Deleted?' editoptions->value string to enable filtering by either an empty or non-empty string?

```
{ name: 'DeletedFlag', index: 'DeletedFlag', hidden: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], searchhidden: true }},
{
   name: 'Deleted?', index: 'DeletedFlag', width: 70, sortable: false, editable: false,
   stype: 'select', /*edittype: 'checkbox',*/ searchoptions: { value: ':All;0:No;1:Yes' }
}
```

EDIT:  posting the entire grid + test data

```
$(function () {
            var grid = $("#PSGrid");

            // get values from Products table
            var prodValues = $.ajax({
                url: "jqGridHandler.ashx?oper=pVals",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            }).responseText;

            // get values from Environments table
            var envValues = $.ajax({
                url: "jqGridHandler.ashx?oper=eVals",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            }).responseText;

            // get values from ServerTypes table
            var typeValues = $.ajax({
                url: "jqGridHandler.ashx?oper=tVals",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            }).responseText;

            var lastsel = -1;

            // build the grid
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
                editurl: 'jqGridEditor.ashx',
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 550,
                width: 'auto',
                colNames: ['ID', 'Product', 'Environment', 'Hostname', 'IP', 'Description', 'Type', 'Ports Used', 'DeletedFlag', 'Deleted?'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 50, sortable: true, hidden: true, editable: false, key: true, sorttype: 'int' },
                    {
                        name: 'Product', index: 'Product', width: 125, sortable: true, editable: true,
                        stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: ':All;' + prodValues, sopt: ['eq'] },
                        formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: prodValues },
                        editrules: { required: true }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Environment', index: 'Environment', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true,
                        stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: ':All;' + envValues, sopt: ['eq'] },
                        formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: envValues },
                        editrules: { required: true }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Hostname', index: 'Hostname', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true,
                        editrules: { required: true }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'IP', index: 'IP', width: 125, sortable: false, editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true,
                        editrules: { required: true }
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Type', index: 'Type', width: 75, sortable: true, editable: true,
                        stype: 'select', searchoptions: { value: ':All;' + typeValues, sopt: ['eq'] },
                        formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: typeValues },
                        editrules: { required: true }
                    },
                    { name: 'Ports Used', index: 'Ports Used', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: true },
                    { name: 'DeletedFlag', index: 'DeletedFlag', hidden: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], searchhidden: true }},
                    {
                        name: 'Deleted?', index: 'Deleted?', width: 70, sortable: false, editable: false,
                        stype: 'select', /*edittype: 'checkbox',*/ searchoptions: { value: ':All;0:No;1:Yes' }
                    }
                ],
                rowNum: 10000, // show all rows hack (-1 is the proper way to do it but is bugged in this version of jqGrid)
                pager: '#PSGridPager',
                sortname: 'ID',
                pgbuttons: false,
                pgtext: null,
                viewrecords: false,
                sortorder: 'asc',
                ignoreCase: true,
                caption: 'Click a row to edit.  [Enter] to save, [Esc] to cancel.',
                loadonce: true,
                onSelectRow: function (id) {
                    if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                        grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                        grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                        lastsel = id;
                    }
                },
                afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                    $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' });
                    alert('hello');
                    return [true];
                }
            });

            grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#PSGridPager', { edit: false, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true, paging: false },
                { /* edit options */ },
                { /* add options */
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    closeAfterAdd: true,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                    width: 400
                },
                { /* delete options */
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    reloadAfterSubmit: true
                });
            grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#PSGridPager', {
                caption: "Export to Excel",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    grid.jqGrid('excelExport', { url: "jqGridHandler.ashx" });
                }
            });
        });
```

Typical row (comma delimited):

'A4', 'Test/QA', 'BLDALTSGPOOFF04', '192.168.86.190', 'IIS 7 Web Farm', 'Web', '80', ''

Comment: Everything is possible, but one need to know how looks like the data returned from the server? Which column of grid have which input data returned from the server? Do you use `filterToolbar` or other searching? By the way usage of `'Deleted?'` as the value of `name` is **very bad**. You should understand the value like the name of property of JavaScript object and like the name used to build `id` property for elements. You should use values typical for identifiers. The value of `index` property must be the same as the value of `name` in case of `loadonce: true` or usage of `datatype: "local"`.

Comment: I'm glad to read that. Could you post examples of the test data which you use? Which kind of searching you use? Is it `filterToolbar` only?

Comment: The mighty Oleg!  I have read so many of your jqGrid answers on this site.  :)

I do use the filterToolbar.  Both these columns receive data from the server.  DeletedFlag receives values of either '0' or '1'.  Deleted? cells receive either empty strings or a timestamp like '2013-06-26 17:02:02.843'.  When DeletedFlag == '0', Deleted? contains an empty string.

Comment: OK! It's clear. Do you use array style of input data (default `repeatitems: true` in `jsonReader`) or the object style (`repeatitems: false`)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the repeatitems property.  It must be the default value because I have not defined it anywhere.

Comment: It seems like the easiest thing would be to filter the Deleted? (name change pending :)) column to show either empty or non-empty cells.  Then I wouldn't even have to get the DeletedFlag column from the server.

Comment: I am back now. At the first look it seems that the *local* filtering of data can do work. You can just use `name: 'IsDeleted', index: 'DeletedFlag'` and verify that `DeletedFlag` field have always some data. I mean that `DeletedFlag` can be `"0"` or `"1"`, but not empty string "" for example. I'll try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to my that you can just use `name: 'IsDeleted', index: 'DeletedFlag'` in the column "IsDeleted". I recommend you rename `name: 'Ports Used', index: 'Ports Used'` to `name: 'PortsUsed', index: 'PortsUsed'` (don't use blanks in the names).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/pelotron.htm) seems to filter the data like you want. I used in the demo the JSON data

```
[
    ["10", "A4", "Test/QA", "BLDALTSGPOOFF04", "192.168.86.190",
     "IIS 7 Web Farm", "Web", "80", "0", ""],
    ["20", "A5", "Test/QA", "BLDALTSGPOOFF05", "192.168.86.178",
     "IIS 6 Web Farm", "Web", "8080", "1", "2013-06-26 17:02:02.843"]
]
```

as the input of the grid.

One more recommendation. You use currently *3 synchronous* Ajax calls (`async: false`) before creating of the grid. I suppose that you can't use `dataUrl` because you use `formatter: 'select'` and you want display data *other* as in the JSON response from the server. Such behavior is not good. I would recommend you to place the same information as the part of main JSON response from `jqGridHandler.ashx`. Inside of `beforeProcessing` callback you can access the data and can use [setColProp](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#add_on_grid_methods) method to change `value` properties of `editoptions` or `searchoptions`. If you do such changes in `beforeProcessing` callback then you do this **before** jqGrid process the JSON response. So jqGrid will used modified values of `value` properties.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I started using jQuery for the first time last week and all your comments have been extremely helpful.

Comment: @pelotron: You are welcome! I hope that you understand my suggestion with `beforeProcessing`. If you would have implementation problem you can ask new question.

Comment: I am trying to implement your suggestion... we shall see how it goes.